# Disadvantages of MongoDB high availability across AWS Regions

Tags: mongodb, high-availability

What are the practical disadvantages of distributing a Mongo 3-node replica set across 3 different regions in AWS for High availability? Or is this a bad idea entirely due to replication lag?

Comment: You should put two nodes at your primary DC, in case of a network partition for example where you still have a majority of servers contacting each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before and it worked quite well.

AWS tends to have very good latency between regions and a hugely redundant network so replication lag is not a problem but you might wish to extend the capped collection oplog a little bit to account for regional problems (i.e. Hurricane Sandy in one region and sunny weather in the other).

As @Orid said you will, of course, want to ensure CAP by keeping a majority in at least one side of the network partition which will exist between regions.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge in advance, but I'm a little confused. What do you mean by 'one side of the network partition which will exist between regions'.

I thought that the reason for splitting the 3-node replica set between regions would be so that if an entire region goes down or becomes unavailable, there are at least 2 nodes which can still see each other so that an election takes place.

If I place a majority in one region, then I wouldn't be able to split my nodes up into 3-regions? or am i getting lost in AWS terminology somewhere?

Comment: @user1891085 this should help: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/505822180/on-distributed-consistency-part-3-network its old but still good

Comment: @user1891085 sorry didn't see your edit, SO no longer notifies me of it. Technically if there was never to be a split between those regions (data centers in this case) then you could actually house a server in each region however any number of things could create a split here whereby partsof the network cannot communicate to each other, as such teh CAP theory takes hold in this case, the majority one side helps prevent the CAP scenario

Comment: OK I understand now. So this actually relates back to the question as the CAP theorem is basically a practical likelihood of storing data disparately. In an ideal world it sounds like a great idea, however to deal with network partitions, the safer bet is to keep the majority on one side. Thanks for your reply, the clarification and the link you sent. Cheers.